# How to get values between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get values between two dates:

```
df[self.cycles.start_date.at[cycle] <= df['visit_date'] <= self.cycles.end_date.at[cycle]]['x']
```

But I get following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How above can be solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, pandas does not support chained comparison. You can use `&` for element-wise comparison. The conditions must be grouped by using parentheses so `&` does not take precedence over comparison operators, as @EdChum noted:

```
df[(self.cycles.start_date.at[cycle] <= df['visit_date']) & (df['visit_date'] <= self.cycles.end_date.at[cycle])]['x']
```